# Not able to delete binary data using python ldap-data

Tags: python-2.7, python-ldap

I am trying to delete an attribute which is binary from an entity using following

```
mod_list = [(ldap.MOD_DELETE, 'attr_name', 'attr_value')]
ldap_con.modify_s('cn=entity_name,ou=entity_ou,dc=entity_dc', mod_list)
```

But this is leading to the issue

```
INAPPROPRIATE_MATCHING: {'info': 'modify/delete: attr_name: no equality matching rule', 'desc': 'Inappropriate matching'}
```

Binary attribute type does not allow any equality matching rule, so I did not put and EQUALITY rule in this attribute definition in schema then what is wrong I am doing here.

Please let me know if there is any other way of deleting binary attribute from an entity in openldap

Comment: Is the attribute type (`attr_name`) a multi-valued attribute?

Comment: No it is not multivalued

Answer (score 0):

At last came to know that it is not possible to delete binary data but we can replace it with empty string.

This is because no 'equality' match available for binary data